# Element fixed to viewport but inside a container

Tags: html, css, container-queries

I'm trying to set up a site with a side panel on the right and the main content on the left. The main content existed already and is fairly complex. The side panel is a new addition and not always visible.

The main content's "responsiveness" should behave different depending on whether the side panel is active or not. E.g. the main content needs to switch from a 3-column-layout to a 1-column-layout at < 800px viewport width when there is no side panel, but already at < 1000px when there is the side panel.

I was able to achieve this by using [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) with the [GoogleChromsLabs Polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/container-query-polyfill).

I'm using container queries because this way I do not have to rewrite every single stylesheet to have extra media queries for when the side panel is present. I can just search&replace every `@media (min-width` with `@container main-content-container (min-width`.

It would be easier if I could just use CSS custom properties in the media query, but unfortunately they don't work that way.

Overall, this works pretty well.

Except for the fixed elements within the main content. Those are now fixed within the container and not the viewport. For example, the nav bar should stick to the top of the window when scrolling down, but it sticks to the top of the container and scrolls out of the viewport.

**Is there way to make it `fixed` relative to the viewport without moving it outside of the container div?**

Example code:

```js
document.querySelector('.toggleContainer').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.main-content').classList.toggle('container')
});

document.querySelector('.toggleSidePanel').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-content').classList.toggle('show')
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto max-content;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: orange;
}

h2 span {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: main-content-container;
}

.container h2 span {
  display: inline;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5rem 1rem;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.side-panel {
  background-color: green;
}

.side-content {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.side-content.show {
  display: block;
}

.fixed-element {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="main-content container">

    <div class="fixed-element">
      Fixed Element
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content <span>(in container)</span></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <button class="toggleContainer">Toggle Container</button>
      <p>
        Lorem 
      </p>
      <button class="toggleSidePanel">Toggle Side Panel</button>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nisi soluta laborum et suscipit deserunt hic consequatur neque accusantium expedita distinctio in cumque quae asperiores cum voluptas, architecto laudantium ipsum nulla!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-panel">

    <div class="side-content show">
      <h2>Side Panel</h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nisi soluta laborum et suscipit deserunt hic consequatur neque accusantium expedita distinctio in cumque quae asperiores cum voluptas, architecto laudantium ipsum nulla!
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

It seems to work when using `sticky` instead of `fixed`.

This probably does not work for every scenario, but it works fairly well for the nav bar.